# <optgroup> in admin form field

Tags: magento-1.9, php, fieldsets

I have an admin form with a few select fields declared in my `_prepareForm` method like the example below:

```php
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'datacenter_action_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/saveConfig'),
        'method' => 'post',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
    ));
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array('legend' => 'Example');
    $fieldset->addField('entity', 'select', array(
        'name' => 'action[entity]',
        'title' => 'Entity',
        'label' => 'Entity',
        'required' => true,
        'values' => array('one','two')
    ));

    ...

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to add `optgroups` to the field values the same way that is possible in `source models` by nesting the values, something like:

```php
...
$fieldset->addField('entity', 'select', array(
        'name' => 'action[entity]',
        'title' => 'Entity',
        'label' => 'Entity',
        'required' => true,
        'values' => array('value' => array('one','two'), 'label' => 'Numbers')
    ));
...
```

Where the expected output would be:

```html
<select>
    <optgroup label="Numbers">
        <option>one</option>
        <option>two</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Obs.: I already tried to model the same way as in the source model (by nesting values), but it don't seemed to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You just need to wrap your options into nested arrays ...

```
            'values'    => [
                [
                    'label' => 'Numbers', #opt1
                    'value' => [
                        [
                            'label' => 'label one',
                            'value' => 'value one',
                        ],
                        [
                            'label' => 'label two',
                            'value' => 'value two',
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'label' => 'Letters', #opt2
                    'value' => [
                        [
                            'label' => 'label A',
                            'value' => 'value A',
                        ],
                        [
                            'label' => 'label B',
                            'value' => 'value B',
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
```

[image]

Comment: Guess I nested it wrong, thankss!